# Remove lines of file B from file A

Tags: bash, parsing, sed

Given two files A and B, remove all lines from file B from file A and count. The script I have so far works for most cases but fails when file_B has special characters ie: `*`, `(`, etc. Is there a better way for me to do this?

## So far

```sh
i=1
while read author
do
  sed -i "s|${author}|[$((i++))]|" file_A
done < file_B
```

## File A:

```
a(n)=my(s="");for(k=1,n,s=Str(s,k));eval(s) \\ _Charles R Greathouse IV_, Sep 19 2012
A007908(n,a=0)={for(d=1,#Str(n),my(t=10^d);for(k=t\10,min(t-1,n),a=a*t+k));a} \\ _M. F. Hasler_, Sep 30 2015
```

## File B:

```
\\ _Charles R Greathouse IV_, Sep 19 2012
\\ _M. F. Hasler_, Sep 30 2015
```

## Output

```
a(n)=my(s="");for(k=1,n,s=Str(s,k));eval(s) [1]
A007908(n,a=0)={for(d=1,#Str(n),my(t=10^d);for(k=t\10,min(t-1,n),a=a*t+k));a} [2]
```

My script fails for:

## Hard file A:

```
   PartitionsQ[Range[0, 60]] (* _Harvey Dale_, Jul 27 2009 *)
   a[ n_] := SeriesCoefficient[ Product[ 1 + x^k, {k, n}], {x, 0, n}]; (* _Michael Somos_, Jul 06 2011 *)
   a[ n_] := SeriesCoefficient[ 1 / Product[ 1 - x^k, {k, 1, n, 2}], {x, 0, n}]; (* _Michael Somos_, Jul 06 2011 *)
   a[ n_] := With[ {t = Log[q] / (2 Pi I)}, SeriesCoefficient[ q^(-1/24) DedekindEta[2 t] / DedekindEta[ t], {q, 0, n}]]; (* _Michael Somos_, Jul 06 2011 *)
   a[ n_] := SeriesCoefficient[ 1 / QPochhammer[ x, x^2], {x, 0, n}]; (* _Michael Somos_, May 24 2013 *)
   a[ n_] := SeriesCoefficient[ Series[ QHypergeometricPFQ[ {q}, {q x}, q, - q x], {q, 0, n}] /. x -> 1, {q, 0, n}]; (* _Michael Somos_, Mar 04 2014 *)
   a[ n_] := SeriesCoefficient[ QHypergeometricPFQ[{}, {}, q, -1] / 2, {q, 0, n}]; (* _Michael Somos_, Mar 04 2014 *)
   nmax = 60; CoefficientList[Series[Exp[Sum[(-1)^(k+1)/k*x^k/(1-x^k), {k, 1, nmax}]], {x, 0, nmax}], x] (* _Vaclav Kotesovec_, Aug 25 2015 *)
   nmax = 100; poly = ConstantArray[0, nmax + 1]; poly[[1]] = 1; poly[[2]] = 1; Do[Do[poly[[j + 1]] += poly[[j - k + 1]], {j, nmax, k, -1}];, {k, 2, nmax}]; poly (* _Vaclav Kotesovec_, Jan 14 2017 *)
```

## Hard file B

```
 _Harvey Dale_, Jul 27 2009 
 _Michael Somos_, Jul 06 2011 
 _Michael Somos_, Mar 04 2014 
 _Michael Somos_, May 24 2013 
 _Vaclav Kotesovec_, Aug 25 2015 
 _Vaclav Kotesovec_, Jan 14 2017
```

## Expected output

```
   PartitionsQ[Range[0, 60]] (* [1] *)
   a[ n_] := SeriesCoefficient[ Product[ 1 + x^k, {k, n}], {x, 0, n}]; (* [2] *)
   a[ n_] := SeriesCoefficient[ 1 / Product[ 1 - x^k, {k, 1, n, 2}], {x, 0, n}]; (* [2] *)
   a[ n_] := With[ {t = Log[q] / (2 Pi I)}, SeriesCoefficient[ q^(-1/24) DedekindEta[2 t] / DedekindEta[ t], {q, 0, n}]]; (* [2] *)
   a[ n_] := SeriesCoefficient[ 1 / QPochhammer[ x, x^2], {x, 0, n}]; (* [3] *)
   a[ n_] := SeriesCoefficient[ Series[ QHypergeometricPFQ[ {q}, {q x}, q, - q x], {q, 0, n}] /. x -> 1, {q, 0, n}]; (* [4] *)
   a[ n_] := SeriesCoefficient[ QHypergeometricPFQ[{}, {}, q, -1] / 2, {q, 0, n}]; (* [4] *)
   nmax = 60; CoefficientList[Series[Exp[Sum[(-1)^(k+1)/k*x^k/(1-x^k), {k, 1, nmax}]], {x, 0, nmax}], x] (* [5] *)
   nmax = 100; poly = ConstantArray[0, nmax + 1]; poly[[1]] = 1; poly[[2]] = 1; Do[Do[poly[[j + 1]] += poly[[j - k + 1]], {j, nmax, k, -1}];, {k, 2, nmax}]; poly (* [6] *)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but fails when file_B has special characters ie: *, (, etc

So escape all those special regex characters.

```
while IFS= read -r author   # this is how to read a line
do
     # escape special character TODO: add more
     author=$(<<<"$author" sed 's/[]\\\*\(\.[]/\\&/g')
     sed -i "s|${author}|[$((i++))]|" file_A
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Following perl one-liner, using quotemeta or `\Q..\E` to quote regex meta character

```
perl -i -pe 'BEGIN{open F,pop or die$!;@A=map{chomp;"\Q$_\E"}<F>}my$i;for$p(@A){++$i;s/$p/[$i]/}' fileA fileB
```

How it works ; Using deparse to be clearer

```
BEGIN { $^I = ".bak"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = readline ARGV)) {
    sub BEGIN {
        die $! unless open F, pop @ARGV;
        @A = map({chomp $_;
        quotemeta $_;} readline F);
    }
    my $i;
    foreach $p (@A) {
        ++$i;
        s/$p/[$i]/;
    }
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

`BEGIN` sub is run before the loop over lines, pops the second argument and read the file filling array @A with the regex pattern quoting meta characters

the loop substitute is similar to sed `s/$p/[$i]/` replaces the pattern `$p` match with index `[$i]`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a simple awk will do the trick here:

```
awk '(NR==FNR){a[$0]="["FNR"]";next}
     { for(string in a) 
         if (n=index($0,string)) 
            $0 = substr($0,1,n-1) a[string] substr($0,n+length(string))
     }
     1' fileA fileB
```

The idea is the read the full list of lines into memory. Each time a line is processed of the second file, we search for a perfect string match of any of the entries of fileA. If a match is found, we substitute the line with the a concatenation of substrings and the replacement string which is stored in `a[string]` as `[FNR]`.

We use the function `index` here to do a perfect string match and avoid characters to be used as regular expression syntax.